# Fastest way to stream out data from Chrome Browser to local machine

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, shared-memory

I like to stream out video data from an HTML, JS, WebGL application on Chrome to the local Linux machine.

While an `XMLHttpRequest` is usually feasable to efficiently push data to the Internet, it is presumably a strong bottleneck if data is to be sent to some receiver on the local machine. An WebGL texture for example, would undergo several transformations (GPU to CPU ram, to JavaScript typed array, to string, through Chrome's net layer, to HTTP, to TCP, to IP...)

Is there any more efficient method to eg. send binary `canvas` contents, or WebGL  framebuffer or texture data to some local machine process? 
If not, would a Chrome extension be access WebGL data and local sockets / shared mmaps / whatever?

Comment: I don't know of any faster way. You can send binary XHRs. You can send binary WebSockets. [Here's one solution](https://github.com/greggman/ffmpegserver.js). I went with text WebSockets because `cavnas.toDataURL` is compressed .PNGs vs sending raw binary or trying to convert the string to binary. In any case it's slow.

Comment: Yes, `toDataURL` is quite slow, as it does PNG compression. Forcing it to do JPG compression is much faster (at least in Chrome), but still to slow for video transfer. `XMLHttpRequest` can transfer a `Blob` on (some?) browsers it seems, that can wrap JS typed arrays, like `Uint32Array`. However, transfering a canvas image to such an array requires several copying steps implemented in JS. (Draw texture to GL framebuffer, read framebuffer to array).

Comment: How well does ffmpegserver perform? Will it do 25fps HD video on larger machines?

Comment: it's very slow. Sending that much data over the network is slow. That's the whole point of compression. To get any speed over the network you'd need to compress in the browser.